# What verb or phrase do you use to say that a person get the job of another person by showing to the boss that they are better at the job?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What verb or phrase do you use to say that a person get the job of another person by showing to the boss that they are better at the job. In Ukrainian we use the verb *підсидіти* to communicate the idea. Can I use the verb *replace*. For example:

> Obviously Kate was better at doing the job than Mike, so she **replaced** him.

Comment: *Take someone's job* comes to my mind, as in *so she **took his job***.

Comment: Obviously _replace_ is what happened, but it doesn't indicate anything about the circumstances - I don't know whether your Ukrainian word does. You might replace a colleague who has retired, for example.